# Django - ManyToMany Field - Make a correct link

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

after an `python3 manager.py inspectdb` (mysql) and a look on few helps and tuto, i still have somes mistakes and incorrect results.

## models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    ida = models.AutoField(db_column='idA', primary_key=True)   
    col1 = #an another column
    has_B = models.ManyToManyField(B, related_name='a', through="AHasB", through_fields=('a_ida', 'b_idb'))
    #I had add this line after a tuto in django book for the manytomayfield

class B(models.Model):
    idb = models.AutoField(db_column='idB', primary_key=True)
    col1 = #an another column

class AHasB(models.Model):
    a_ida = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b_idb = models.ForeignKey(B)
    col1 = #an another column
```

## view.py

```
def myview(request):

   for element in b.filter(idb__in=a.values('has_B').distinct()):

      print(element)
```

In my database i have,

```
A : 
ida  | col1  
1    | ...   
2    | ... 
3    | ... 

B : 
idb  | col1  
1    | ...   

AHasB : 
a_ida  | b_idb  
1      | 1
```

But when i will display result (`ida -> idb`) like a classic (`SELECT idb,ida FROM A, B, AHasB WHERE AHasB.a_ida=A.ida AND AHasB.b_idb=B.idb`), i have this ...

```
1  ->  1
2  ->  1
3  ->  1
```

And in normal case, i will just have  1  ->  1.

Maybe the model dont fit with my real database in back.

## Edit

### view.py

```
def myview(request):

   a = A.objects.All()
   b = B.objects.All()

   for element_a in a.filter("somefilters"):

      in_has_b = set(AHasB.objects.values_list('b_idb', flat=True));
      print(b.filter(idb__in=in_has_b))
```

Comment: So you want to select all B instances that are referenced / owned by A instances? If so you could simply try `in_has_b = set(AHasB.objects.values_list('b_idb', flat=True)); B.objects.filter(id__in=in_has_b)`

Comment: Are your code is real and working? There is no idB column in model B: `idb = models.AutoField(db_column='idA', primary_key=True)`

Comment: @AmaroVita no it's a example. And ty for your post it was a mistake in my example. you win a cookie =)

Comment: @Pawamoy It's work but not perfectly i use this function in loop (i edit my post). It's will be great if i know how add your line code with `element_a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all B instances that are referenced / owned by each A instance:

```
bs_for_each_a = {}

for a in A.objects.all():
   bs = AHasB.objects.filter(a_ida=a).values('b_idb')
   bs_for_each_a[a] = bs
```

If you need distinct Bs, you can try to add `.distinct()` after `values('b_idb')` but I did not test it. Another way to remove duplicates would be to use `values_list('b_idb', flat=True)` and pass the result of the query in `set()`:

```
for a in A.objects.all():
   bs = AHasB.objects.filter(a_ida=a).values_list('b_idb', flat=True)
   bs_for_each_a[a] = set(bs)
```

Comment: Perfect =) You win a jar full of cookies ;)